# SyntaxError: invalid syntax .. Getting error in f-strings in Python

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,11):    
    m  = n*i
    print(f"{n} * {i} = {m}")
```

I am trying to run this code but I am getting the error message below.

```
  File "main.py", line 4                                                                                                                
    print(f"{n} * {i} = {m}")                                                                                                           
                           ^                                                                                                            
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                        
...Program finished with exit code 1                                                                                                    
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

I am using online compiler - onlinegdb python

Comment: above code is working for me

Comment: try using .format() instead of f-string

Answer (score 2):

The following will reveal the used Python version:

```
import sys

print(sys.version_info)
```

If you run this, the output in https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler is:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

This is Python Version 3.4.3. [F-strings are only a Python feature since 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498), so no surprise there.